# .htaccess multuple redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need 3 different rules

1: if the url is `www.test.com` -> redirect to `www.test.com/go` (which /go just has index.php)

2: if the url is `www.test.com/go` -> redirect to same above ^

3: if the url is `www.test.com/(anything but go)` -> stay on `index.php` but add `page=$1`. So it sits it `www.test.com?page=enteredText`

I have the redirect working only if you enter /go it takes you to /go/index.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/go
RewriteRule .* /index.php?page=$1
```

But now I need to add the other two rules and I am not to sure how to go about it without getting stuck in a loop of rules 2 and 3 stepping on eachother.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rules and conditions clear cache beforehand,

```
RewriteRule ^$ /go [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/go
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The redirects work but now, all ajax calls on index.php are submitting to the same index.php file like the page was being refreshed?

Comment: I am not getting the context but the rule is working as you mentioned in requirements. you might have to change some links maybe.